# Powery query - Sort by Date - Current day minus 1

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to sort within power query to sort by current day minus 1.

I've been able to sort for the current date using:

Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))

Any suggestions on how to return the previous day?

Answer (score 1):

That would be: Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())),-1)